# How to edit the header layout of a child theme in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm freshy in terms of PHP and WordPress. Atm I have a childtheme that has a header.php file. I managed to include h2 below h1 using HTML when I viewed source of the website in the style I need it in, but I am unsure how to do that outside the HTML to force it to become a permanent feature of the website.

What I'm trying to do;

- Insert ability to include h2 below h1
- Edit the h2 to desirable text

It's a relatively simple thing, but I cannot seem to manipulate wordpress in a way that would allow me to make that change to a child theme.

Comment: The html you see in the page source is the end result. If you need to make any permanent changes then makes them inside the header.php file of your child-theme. Wordpress takes a bunch of php template files and merges them into one html document in order to produce a page. If you need to modify what the end result - or html document - looks like permanently...then you need to modify the template. In your case the template is the header.php file of your child theme.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I thought I was looking in the right place. I managed to locate the file in the editor and I found a piece of code that referenced #header .blogname h1. Now, I am unsure what to take from this, as the code following that was a bit more than I can yet digest. 

My final question in that case; How can I preserve the formatting that h2 came up as in HTML edit in developer tools? By just injecting <h2> under <h1>, it was neatly formatted, but h1 was applied through a customize menu in 'Logo and Title' menu, which only allows h1 titles. 

I'm sorry if I don't make much sense.

Comment: No, it's no problem. Wordpress themes have CSS files in which all the styling information is stored. If your theme has specific styles it applies to `<h2>` tags then the formatting will be automatic just like in the case where you manually injected the `<h2>` tag in the html page source. Long story short, yes you can try to add the`<h2>` under the `<h1>` - if that's where you'd like to `<h2>` to be - in your child-theme's `header.php` and your theme's default `<h2>` styling will most likely be applied to it automatically.

Comment: Depends on what the h1 is. Is it a title tag? If it is, there shoudl be a get_the_title() function in header, simply insert the h2 right after it. If its part of the content, you will need to split get_the_content() and insert it there and echo it back out. If you provide a copy of the header.php, it would help greatly.